# React App becoming unresponsive after a few clicks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-state

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import {Map, Marker, TileLayer, Popup} from "react-leaflet";
import { Sidebar, Tab } from 'react-leaflet-sidetabs';
import WINLogo from './imgs/WINLogo.png'
import { FiChevronRight } from "react-icons/fi";
import { FaMapMarkedAlt } from "react-icons/fa"
import WomenInTheWorld from "./Components/WomenInTheWorldData";
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import projectCenters from "./Components/IQPLocations";
import L from 'leaflet';
import './App.css';
import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import {setPosition} from "leaflet/src/dom/DomUtil";

delete L.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;

L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
  iconRetinaUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png'),
  iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'),
  shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png')
});

var popup = L.popup();

var markerLayers = {};

var currentCountry;


var WCenters = [];
let WCenterInfo = [];
var sponsorInfo = {};
var filteredInfo = {};
var currentInfo = {};

const colnames = [
  {
    title: 'Title', field: 'Title'
  },
  {
    title: 'Location', field: 'ProjectCenter_y'
  },
  {
    title: 'Sponsor', field: 'Sponsor'
  },
  {
    title: 'Date', field: 'Date'
  },
  {
    title: 'Link', field: 'Link'
  }
]


function FindingProjectCenters() {
  projectCenters.forEach(function (key) {
    WomenInTheWorld.forEach(function (Center) {
      if (key.name === Center.ProjectCenter_x){
        WCenters.push(key);
        WCenterInfo.push(Center);
      }
    });
  })
}

FindingProjectCenters();
let uniqueCenters = [...new Set(WCenters)]

function showPopup(){
  this.openPopup();
}

function hidePopup(){
  this.closePopup();
}


export default class App extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      collapsed: true,
      selected: 'home',
    };
  }

  onClose() {
    this.setState({collapsed: true});
  }
  onOpen(id) {
    this.setState({
      collapsed: false,
      selected: id,
    })
  }

  handleClick = (country) => (e) => {
    WCenterInfo = [];
    WomenInTheWorld.forEach(function (Center) {
      if (country === Center.ProjectCenter_x){
        WCenterInfo.push(Center);
      }
    });
    this.onOpen("settings");
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Fragment>
          <Sidebar
              id="sidebar"
              position="right"
              collapsed={this.state.collapsed}
              closeIcon={<FiChevronRight />}
              selected={this.state.selected}
              onOpen={this.onOpen.bind(this)}
              onClose={this.onClose.bind(this)}
          >
            <Tab id="settings" header="Project Centers" icon={<FaMapMarkedAlt />}>
              <div>
                <Box mt={2} />
                <MaterialTable title="IQPs"
                               columns={colnames}
                               data={WCenterInfo}
                               options={{
                                 search: true,
                                 exportButton: true,
                                 pageSize:5,
                                 pageSizeOptions: [10]
                               }}/>
              </div>
            </Tab>
          </Sidebar>
          <div className="WinLogo">
            <img src={WINLogo} alt="WIN"></img>
          </div>
            <Map style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100%" }} className="mapStyle" center={[0, 0]} zoom={3}>
              <TileLayer
                  attribution='Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, DeLorme, NAVTEQ, USGS, Intermap, iPC, NRCAN, Esri Japan, METI, Esri China (Hong Kong), Esri (Thailand), TomTom, 2012'
                  url={'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'}
              />
              {uniqueCenters.map((center, k) => {
                let position = [center["coordinates"][0], center["coordinates"][1]]
                return (
                    <Marker
                        key={k}
                        onMouseOver={(e) => {
                          e.target.openPopup();
                        }}
                        onMouseOut={(e) => {
                          e.target.closePopup();
                        }}
                        onClick={this.handleClick(center.name)}
                        position={position}
                    >
                      <Popup> {center.name} </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                )
              })
              }
            </Map>
        </Fragment>
    )
  }

}
```

Hi Everyone,
I have created a interactive map using react-leaflet. The purpose of the app is to have markers that have project center locations off all the study abroad that my school has. After clicking on the marker I have to make a table that gives the some data on Project Center. I have been able to achieve this by creating a array and changing it using the country information I get after clicking on the marker. After changing the array I build a material-ui table with it. This works for a few clicks however it becomes unresponsive after a while. I would greatly appreciate some help with this.

Comment: could you create a demo of your app to reproduce the issue?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/live/7iizsvq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: the link does not work for some reason